# Appending data to text file dependant on if statment

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, append, match

I am trying to get a text file automatically updating new class details.

```
# Example variables
completed = Yes
class = 13A
time = 11:00

if completed:
    # Check data class and time variables against text file and if they don't exist then add them, if they do exist do nothing.
```

My text files look like:

```
13A
11:00
Top Students: Joe Smith, Tom Clarke, Jenna Sole
Top 3 
Attendance: 98.5%
Class Score: 54
Yes

13B
11:10
Top Students: Anni Moy, Jessica Longate, Phillip Tome
T3 
Attendance: 98.5%
Class Score: 54
Yes

14A
11:10
Top Students: John Doe, John Smith, Sam Ben
T2 
Attendance: 98.5%
Class Score: 54
Yes
```

Does any one know how this can be done, I would greatly appreciate an example if anyone could be so helpful.

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself yet? What problems did you encounter?

Comment: Yes, I have indeed tried stuff myself but I am unsure/unable to do a regex check/match using `split('/n/n')` to split the data into items and then matching/checking each one.

Comment: One quick and dirty way: `completed = (class + '\n' + time) in file.read()`

Comment: @Michael0x2a `completed` isn't the result of `class` + `time` being successfully matched in each "item" within the text file, instead `completed` is the trigger to tell the code to check `time` and `class` against the file.

Comment: Ah. Then, use a different variable name and do the check inside the `if` statement?

Comment: I will do, I was just explaining just incase someone wants to give another alternative suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the code that parses the text file and dumps them into variables.
Code below illustrates how to parse your text file using regex.

```
import re

fp = open('class_data.txt')
lines = fp.read(-1)
fp.close()

records = re.split('\n\s*\n', lines) #Split all the records
#print len(records)
for record in records:
    data =  record.split('\n')
    classid, classtime, top_students = data[0], data[1], re.split('^[A-Za-z ]*:', data[2])[1].split(',')
    attendance, score, completed = re.split('^[A-Za-z ]*:', data[4])[1], re.split('^[A-Za-z ]*:', data[5])[1], data[6]
    print classid, classtime, top_students, len(top_students), attendance, score, completed
```

Print statement outputs

```
13A 11:00 [' Joe Smith', ' Tom Clarke', ' Jenna Sole'] 3  98.5%  54 Yes
13B 11:10 [' Anni Moy', ' Jessica Longate', ' Phillip Tome'] 3  98.5%  54 Yes
14A 11:10 [' John Doe', ' John Smith', ' Sam Ben'] 3  98.5%  54 Yes
```

Now that you have your text file converted into variables, We can now add the code to check whether a class is finished and if the record is already contained in the file else add it

```
import re

fp = open('class_data.txt')
lines = fp.read(-1)
fp.close()

completed = Yes
class = 13A
time = 11:00  
isClassRecordFound = False

records = re.split('\n\s*\n', lines) #Split all the records
#print len(records)
for record in records:
    data =  record.split('\n')
    classid, classtime, top_students = data[0], data[1], re.split('^[A-Za-z ]*:', data[2])[1].split(',')
    attendance, score, completed = re.split('^[A-Za-z ]*:', data[4])[1], re.split('^[A-Za-z ]*:', data[5])[1], data[6]
    print classid, classtime, top_students, len(top_students), attendance, score, completed 
    if (completed):
        if (classid == class) and (time == classtime):
             isClassRecordFound = True
             break;
if not isClassRecordFound:
    with open("class_data.txt", "a") as myfile:
        myfile.write(class + '\n' + time)
```

Comment: Hmm, way off from what I was trying, no wonder my attempts failed. This works perfectly. Awarded the green tick + upvote :) Thanks.